# D3 issue in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, d3.js

I have an simple issue with D3 in IE9.

Have a look at this example both in Chrome/Firefox and IE9.
--> http://bl.ocks.org/d/1005873/

Click on one block to use the zoom functionality. 
It works on Chrome, but IE9 is not able to "hide" all the other elements when zooming. The content out of the "div" block is shown.

I am wondering how this issue can be solved. One way is to integrate the chart in a iframe, like on this page : http://bl.ocks.org/1005873

but I was wondering if there was a better way to set D3 in order to avoid the iframe workaround.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've tried IE and Chrome and I don't see a difference?

Comment: @Robuust In Chrome the graph is limited to 960px wide, in IE9 the graphs length increases when you zoom since the 'unzoomed' part of the graph isn't correctly hidden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix this issue, you can add a width and hide the overflow for the `chart` div.  After adding the following, IE9 works as expected for me.

```
<div id="chart" style="width: 960px; overflow: hidden;">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it was as expected!